# Can I integrate botium Bindings with Jenkins or any other CI/CD tool? if so, How Can I?

Tags: npm, automation, chatbot

> How Can I integrate botium bindings with Jenkis ?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing specific with Botium Binding to integrate it in Jenkins, it's just as any other Node.js/Mocha project.

1. Place the Botium Project (with package.json and botium.json) in a Git repository
2. Link your Jenkins project with the Git repository
3. Create a script build task "npm install && mocha --reporter=xunit > testresults.xml"
4. As post-build action, publish the JUnit test results in the testresults.xml file

There is [another mocha reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-jenkins-reporter) available than the integrated XUNIT one, providing better integration with Jenkins.

**Botium Box** is prepared to be integrated into a CI/CD pipeline, you can find more information about it in the [Botium Wiki](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/33282/CI+CD+Integration), and [here are instructions specific to Botium Box with Jenkins](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/45842433/Add+Botium+Test+Suite+to+Jenkins+Pipeline).